# Is it possible to set the SUPPORTED_GROUPS extension to one of the "ffdhe" groups when using s_client?

Tags: openssl

I need to validate that a server is correctly handling the SUPPORTED_GROUPS extension when using one of the DHE key exchange ciphersuites.  OpenSSL's `s_client` has an option named `groups`, and it works fine with EC groups, but I get a very unhelpful `Error with command: "-groups ffdhe2048"` message whenever I try to specify one of the ffdhe group names from `rfc7919`.

For example:

```
>openssl.exe version
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020

>openssl.exe s_client -host 127.0.0.1 -port 9012 -groups ffdhe2048 -cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 -msg -debug
Error with command: "-groups ffdhe2048"
```

I've tried all the variations I can think of on case and name (`FFDHE2048`, `dhe2048`, `ffdh2048`, etc).  But in the source, it's pretty clearly `ffdhe2048`.  Sadly, there's no `-list_curves` for `dhparam` like there is for `ecparam`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that sending ffdhe groups in the supported_groups extension is only relevant for TLSv1.3 connections in OpenSSL 1.1.1. If you are using TLSv1.2 or below then any ffdhe groups are ignored. I mention this because you explicitly request the TLSv1.2 ciphersuite `DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384` in your command line above. This will also be ignored if TLSv1.3 ends up being negotiated, so that's fine (but might not be what you intended to happen).

Unfortunately OpenSSL 1.1.1 does not support ffdhe groups in TLSv1.3. OpenSSL 3.0 (currently in alpha testing as of the time of writing) does support it. So if I try your command line in OpenSSL 3.0 then it works. If I setup an OpenSSL 3.0 s_server instance for the server end of the connection then a TLSv1.3 connection is established and ffdhe2048 is used for key exchange.

Comment: RFC 7919 "Negotiated Finite Field Diffie-Hellman Ephemeral Parameters for Transport Layer Security (TLS)" includes the following text in the Abstract section: "This document updates TLS versions 1.0 (RFC 2246), 1.1 (RFC 4346), and 1.2 (RFC 5246)...". I think both EC and negotiated DH is relevant for all versions of TLS. It may be the case that by default OpenSSL does not implement this functionality, but this does not mean that SUPPORTED_GROUPS is TLS v1.3 only extension. At least not according to RFC.

Comment: You are correct! Thanks for pointing that out. I have corrected my answer accordingly, i.e. to make it say I am referring to what is implemented in OpenSSL.